# Setting a parent of a QTForm - Resizing to the actual form size

Tags: c++, qt

Say I have a form form_child and another form called form_parent. Now when I display form_child from form_parent. form_Child also appears in the taskbar. In order for it to stop doing that I was told to make form_parent the parent of the form_child form. After doing that I realized the size of form_child changes and it seems to me the child form got pasted in the parent form. Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue. Here is what I am trying

```
form_child *u = new form_child(this);  //this ptr is the address of parent form
u->setFixedSize(u->size());
u->show();
```

How can I make child form not appear in the task bar at the same time making sure it does not appear inside the parent form and has its own size set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add *[Qt::Dialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum)* window flag to it's current window flags: `u->setWindowFlags(u->windowFlags() | Qt::Dialog);` or derive the `form_child` class from [QDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#details) instead of QWidget or QMainWindow.